# Deleting blank pages in large documents

Tags: vba, ms-word

We use SAS to output to rtf files then compile a load together, creating very large documents in most cases. But when compiling these outputs into one single document blank pages are sometimes created and we need to go through searching for and deleting these pages.

The code I have so far seems to work for the most part, but I am coming across a memory error on some occasions and wondering if anyone has suggestions to improve the code?

The following is the start of the code which is where I am getting the memory error on some occasions:

```vb
Sub BlankPage()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Options.Pagination = False
Dim i As Long, Rng As Range, Blank As Integer, Page() As Long

With ActiveDocument
Blank = 0
For i = 1 To .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)
  Set Rng = .GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=i)
  Set Rng = Rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page")
  If Len(Rng) < 3 Then
    Blank = Blank + 1
    ReDim Preserve Page(Blank)
    If Blank = 1 Then
      Page(Blank) = Rng.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
    Else
      Page(Blank) = ((Rng.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) - Blank) + 1)
    End If
  End If
Next i
Application.Options.Pagination = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

If Blank = 1 Then
  MsgBox "Found " & Blank & " page to check"
Else
  MsgBox "Found " & Blank & " pages to check"
End If

Dim j As Long, StrPages As String, intResponse As Integer, No As Long
No = 0
If Blank > 0 Then
  For j = 1 To Blank
    Set Rng = .GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=((Page(j) + No))
    Set Rng = Rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page")
    Selection.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext, Name:=(Page(j) + No))
    intResponse = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this page?", vbYesNo)
    If intResponse = vbYes Then
      StrPages = StrPages & " " & Rng.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
      Rng.Delete
    Else
      No = No + 1
    End If
  Next j
End If
```

End With

Comment: which line gives you the exception?

Comment: I am not sure if it is related to a specific line, or if it is just using to much memory in general when used on large documents. I just get the 'insufficient memory' pop-up on some occasions and get kicked out of word.

Comment: Well `ReDim Preserve` surely isn't helping you.

Comment: I am using that to store the page numbers of blank pages found, which I then use in another loop after this section to take the user to each page and ask if they want to delete it. Not sure on other ways this can be done, I have only been learning in my spare time for a month so don't know much yet.

Comment: you can try Ctrl + Shift + 8 (`Ctrl + *`) to see if all of the blank pages contain just a page break. If that is the case, then adjusting the margins a bit, or replacing the page breaks with Find and Replace might be an easier option.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat messy and more of a hack because I don't have your data (and therefore I am not sure what `Len(rng) < 3` is about, but you can add another loop to declare your array size one time, instead of doing it for each loop.

This can either result in a performance loss or performance gain (I would think gain since you are not constantly using `ReDim Preserve`).

```
Sub BlankPage()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Options.Pagination = False
Dim i As Long, Rng As Range, Blank As Integer, Page() As Long

With ActiveDocument
Blank = 0

'Get the array size ONE time only
For i = 1 To .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)
    If Len(Rng) < 3 Then Blank = Blank + 1
Next
ReDim Page(Blank)   '< -- You ReDim only once -- <
Blank = 0

For i = 1 To .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)
    Set Rng = .GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=i)
    Set Rng = Rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page")
    If Len(Rng) < 3 Then
        blank = blank + 1
        If Blank = 1 Then   '< --  remove the ReDim preserve -- <
            Page(Blank) = Rng.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
        Else
            Page(Blank) = ((Rng.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) - Blank) + 1)
        End If
    End If
Next i

Application.Options.Pagination = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have just added the next section of my code to give you more information on what I am doing. The 'Len(Rng) < 3' is just checking the length of the contents of each page it goes through and if it is less than 3 those page numbers are stored to take the user through each page found in the next loop

Comment: @DannyPurvis Did you try the portion I fixed first? Because Preserving a large array can be memory intensive.

Comment: Not yet, sorry. I will do and will let you know how it goes, it may be tomorrow when I can give a better answer. Since the error I am getting doesn't occur every time I will need to test this on a few documents and it is 10pm here now. Thanks again, as I said I am still learning the capabilities of VBA and am pretty sure my code can be improved. I just don't know how yet :)